# How do I perform a transaction in firebase_database in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

How do I perform an atomic read/write transaction in firebase_database in Flutter?

Comment: When posting to Stack Overflow, please don't post pictures of code and errors. Instead, it's much better to copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: Firebase transactions are going to work the same way with flutter as they do with other languages.  Try starting with the documentation for transactions for one of the other supported languages to get a sense of how they work.

Comment: The photos above contain context that cannot be described in text, and all important code is already in text.

Comment: I know how to achieve this in JavaScript but I am unable to complete the task in this context.

Comment: Closest match is probably Android.  The semantics of the various objects and callbacks are unchanged.

Comment: I've been through the Java examples as well and they do not shed light on this. The semantics of the various objects and callbacks are not the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/175996/discussion-between-luke-pighetti-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to include the differences in semantics that you observed, that might help.  For example, you could say "this is what the code would look like in language X, but I'm unable to translate these concepts to Y".  I personally can't help because I haven't written a line of Dart in my life.  But I know that transactions functionally work very similarly everywhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A transaction is an atomic read/write on a piece of data in a Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore.

Flutter is a mobile development framework that uses the Dart language.

This is how you perform a transaction using the firebase_database package in a Flutter app.

```
final dataRef = database.reference().child('path/to/data');

dataRef.runTransaction((MutableData transaction) async{
    transaction.value = (transaction.value ?? 0) + 1;
    return transaction;
});
```

Comment: I am trying do this way and getting an error, some idea?: java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: FirebaseDatabaseWorker

Comment: It gives "Undefined name 'database'." you should edit your question for newbies.